# JQuery: Attaching input form to input field in datepicker style

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-input

I want to display an input form attached to an input field like the datepicker does.

I've tried the "show" function, but instead of displaying the input form overlaid, it shows what was hidden and moves the rest of the page down.

There are many overlay libraries out-there, but none (that I've seen) attaches the overlaid form to the input field, like the "datepicker" does.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? (preferably no other external libraries, other than jQuery or jQuery UI).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is CSS related.

Just apply some absolute positioning on the DIV you're showing via .show().

Example :

```
// jQuery is :
$('#yourDiv').addClass('yourDivClass');

/* CSS is : */
.yourDivClass {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

Adjust left and top values to your likings.

Comment: If I get it right: the absolute position attribute will display the input on an exact position on the display (relative to 0,0).
But what I meant is: I want the input to be displayed (in the overlay style) just under the input field ... like the datepicker does.
Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly, it is also according to the parent DIV. Play with it on a test page and see how it can fit you :-). Also remember to use `display: block;`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no library or plugin for this (correct me if I'm wrong). You should use CSS absolute positioning for the form, and set the `top`/`left` properties on the form to the `offset` of the input field. Here is a quick example of how I'd do it: http://jsfiddle.net/85ZkV/